# Using Play's JSON autoformatting when json property names don't match

Tags: json, scala, playframework

My JSON result have the naming convention like:

```
"account_id"
"location_type"
```

But my case classes have:

```
case class Employee(accountId: Int, locationType: String)
```

Is there a way to override the case classes property when JSON is being parsed?

Automapping: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonAutomated

Answer (score 4):

There are two things you can do here:

1. Rename fields in your case class:

   ```
   case class Employee(account_id: Int, location_type: String)
   ```
2. Write your custom `Format`:

   ```
   import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
   import play.api.libs.json._

   implicit val employeeFormat: Format[Employee] = (
     (__ \ "account_id").format[Int] and
     (__ \ "location_type").format[String]
   )(Employee.apply, unlift(Employee.unapply))
   ```